# Collision Detection: What side was hit? [Java,Slick2D]

Tags: java, collision-detection, slick2d, bounding-box

I have two rectangles, r1 which is moving, and r2 which is a stationary tile. I need to know what side of r2 (or r1) is hit to determine which direction r1 should go. The collision detection works with the shape.intersects(otherShape), unfortunately this means that r1 will "Sink" a few pixels inside of r2. This is very problematic when dealing with the corners of the rectangles since this will cause two sides of each rectangle to intersect, thus making figuring out what side was hit by checking what side intersects which to be ineffective.

What we know:

- Positions and Center positions of r1 and r2
- Velocities and speeds of r1 and r2

So given that information, i need an algorithm that is able to get the side of collision.

Answer (score 0):

A square is defined by four corners, the upper-left, upper-right, lower-left, lower-right. If your updates/collisiondetections are fast enough then the following will work. This takes into consideration the event that only one corner collides (if your rectangle rotates or moves in 2D).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestMovingRect extends JComponent {
JFrame frame;
Rectangle2D r1;
Rectangle2D r2;
int speedX, speedY;
int width = 20;
int height = 20;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestMovingRect();
}

public TestMovingRect() {
    r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
    r2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(200, 0, width, height);
    speedX = 1;
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    loop();
}

public void tick(){
    System.out.println("Old r1: " + r1.getX() + "," + r1.getY());
    double x = r1.getX();
    double y = r1.getY();
    r1.setRect(x + speedX, y + speedY, 10, 10);
    System.out.println("New r1: " + r1.getX() + "," + r1.getY());

}

private void loop() {
    while (true){
        tick();
        sleep();
        checkIntersect();
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

private void checkIntersect() {
    Point2D upperLeft = new Point2D.Double(r1.getX(), r1.getY());
    Point2D upperRight = new Point2D.Double(r1.getX() + r1.getWidth(),
            r1.getY());
    Point2D lowerLeft = new Point2D.Double(r1.getX(), r1.getY()
            + r1.getHeight());
    Point2D lowerRight = new Point2D.Double(r1.getX() + r1.getWidth(),
            r1.getY() + r1.getHeight());

    if (r2.contains(upperRight)){
        System.out.println("UpperRight hit");
        //Do stuff
    }

    if (r2.contains(lowerRight)) {
        System.out.println("lowerRight hit");
        // Do stuff
    }

    if (r2.contains(lowerLeft)) {
        System.out.println("LowerLeft hit");
        // Do stuff
    }

    if (r2.contains(upperLeft)) {
        System.out.println("UpperLeft hit");
        // Do stuff
    }
}

private void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect((int) r1.getX(), (int) r1.getY(), (int) r1.getWidth(),
            (int) r1.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect((int) r2.getX(), (int) r2.getY(), (int) r2.getWidth(),
            (int) r2.getHeight());
}


 }
```

Another (far simpler) way is to interpolate the velocity of the rectangle. If it is moving to the right and it intersects then you know it must have hit the right side. But then if your rectangle is rotating or moving in 2D you will have added complexity and the above code would do just as fine.

Edit: To your comment

```
if (r2.contains(upperRight)){
        if (speedX * speedX > speedY * speedY) {
            System.out.println("I hit on the right side");
        }

        else if (speedY * speedY > speedX * speedX) {
            System.out.println("I  hit on the topside");
        }

        else if (speedX * speedX == speedY * speedY) {
            System.out
                    .println("I hit on a 45 degree diagonal, side is ambigious, please decide for me");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think this algorithm will work. I'm looking to get the side of r1 that is hit. While this code is useful in telling me which corner of r1 was hit, it doesn't tell me which side was hit. Consider the event where the bottom right corner of r2 is inside of the top right corner of r1. While from this information I can tell that either the top or left side of r1 was hit, it unfortunately doesn't tell me which one.

Comment: If r1 moves into r2 from the right and only the top-right corner of r1 sinks into r2 (due to different wids, different y-poistions) then you can't know if the collision was from the right side of r1 or from its topside by collisiondetection unless you take into consideration what direction it came from (speed).

Comment: I am wondering why you are multiplying the speed. Wouldn't speedX * speedX > speedY * speedY always return the same thing as speedX > speedY?

Comment: So I wouldn't have to worry about the sign of the speed. You could just do Math.abs(speedX)>Math.abs(speedY)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but a different problem arises now. Consider that the rectangle is moving at V(1,9) and collides with the right side of tile. According to the added portion of code, it would print out that it hit the top instead of the right.

Comment: Only a problem if they start very close together. Specifically what are you trying to do? Reverse the velocity of a rectangle if it collides with another?